# ¿Cómo guardar múltiples archivos desde Angular a API de Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy tratando de guardar varios archivos enviados desde Angular a una API de Laravel, sin embargo, no logro guardarlos, únicamente guardar uno.

**Aquí está el código de la API donde guarda los archivos:**

```
 public function uploadFile(Request $request)
{   
    $lengthFiles = (int)$request->length;          
    if($lengthFiles > 1){        
        if($request->hasFile('arrayFiles')){
            foreach ($request->file('arrayFiles') as $file){                    
                $fileFullName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileFullName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $fileWithoutSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $fileName );          
                $fileLower = Str::lower($fileWithoutSpaces); 
                $newFileName = "pdf_".$fileLower."_".now()->second.now()->day.now()->year.now()->minute.now()->hour.".".$file->guessExtension();       
                $finalPath = public_path("public-files/events-files/" . $newFileName);
                if($file->guessExtension() == "pdf"){
                    copy($file, $finalPath);                  
                }else{
                    return ($this->errorResponse('El archivo que intentas subir no es un PDF', 422));
                }    
            }
        }
    }else if($lengthFiles == 1){      
        if($request->hasFile('arrayFiles')){    
            $file = $request->file("arrayFiles");
            $fileFullName = $request->file('arrayFiles')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileFullName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $fileWithoutSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $fileName );          
            $fileLower = Str::lower($fileWithoutSpaces); 
            $newFileName = "pdf_".$fileLower."_".now()->second.now()->day.now()->year.now()->minute.now()->hour.".".$file->guessExtension();       
            $finalPath = public_path("public-files/events-files/" . $newFileName);
            if($file->guessExtension() == "pdf"){
                copy($file, $finalPath);                  
            }else{
                return ($this->errorResponse('El archivo que intentas subir no es un PDF', 422));
            }      
        }       
    }
}
```

En el código anterior válido la cantidad de archivos que recibe, dependiendo de si es uno, guárdelo sin realizar el foreach, y si es mayor a uno, haga el foreach y procese el nombre y finalmente guardarlo en la ruta especificada.

**Aquí está el código de Angular dónde envía los archivos**

```
 var lengthFiles:any = Object.values(counts);
    var formDataFile = new FormData();
    formDataFile.append('arrayFiles', this.arrayFiles);    
    formDataFile.append('length', lengthFiles);
                      
    this._eventService.upload(formDataFile).then((response:any) => {
       this.progress = 1;
    }).catch((response: any) => {
         this.progress = false;
    });
```

Ahí envío los archivos haciendo la instancia FormData y enviando la cantidad de archivos y el archivo para validarlo en el backend.

Así se vería el array de archivos:
[image: Array]

**A continuación les muestro cómo se está enviado la data:**

[image: data]

Edit:

*Como se envia la data de los archivos desde el frontend*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, supongo que subes los archivos múltiples en un `input type="file" multiple`, es correcto..?? este es `arrayFiles` es tu frond..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, te daré un ejemplo sencillo de lo que tienes que hacer en el *Laravel*, la verdad no necesitas la variable `$lengthFiles` solo obtienes el numero de archivos así:

```php
public function uploadFile(Request $request)
{
  $count = count($request->file());

  if($count > 0){
    foreach($request->file() as $item){
      //acá almacenas cada archivo, un pequeño ejemplo:
      $item->storeAs('files/', 'nombre-del-archivo');
      //tú coloca la lógica que necesites para almacenar cada archivo :) 
    }
  }
```

Y en tu frond agrega los archivos con un `forEach`

```js
this.arrayFiles.forEach((item, index) => {
   formDataFile.append('file-'+index, item)
})
```

Espero te sirva, saludos...

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu retroalimentación.
Seguí al pie tus recomendaciones, sin embargo, no logro cargar todos, solo carga 1 archivo, creo que el problema radica en el Laravel, realicé la prueba desde el Postman, y adjuntando más de 1 archivo, me sale que solo recibe uno con el  $count = count($request->file());

Comment: @user0972083 primero que nada, una pregunta, ¿estas enviando el *headers* `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` en tu solicitud? puede ser por múltiples razones, pero revisa primero los *headers*

Comment: Si puedes, edita tu pregunta y adiciona los datos de tu solicitud, los que te muestra el `network` de tu navegador, allí mismo podrás ver si realmente se están enviando mas de un archivo ;)

Comment: El parámetro headers 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' lo pongo desde el postman y recibo un error, sin embargo, probaré a ponerlo desde el Angular. Y respondiendo sobre lo que se envía, ya edito y lo pongo

Comment: Vale, el encabezado debiera ser bien recibido, desconozco porque *Postman* te esta dando el error, prueba en *Angular* como dices, si no funciona, queda por chequear las configuraciones de *PHP* aunque creo que de ser eso *Laravel* deberia responder con `413 Payload Too Large` pero tal vez deberías revisar eso

Comment: Hay ciertas configuraciones que tienes que tomar en cuenta en tu `php.ini` el cual se encuentra, de estar en linux en `/etc/php/7.*/apache2` o `/etc/php/7.*/cli`. por ultimo puede ser simplemente tu código en el controlador

Comment: [content-length](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#:~:text=The%20Content%2DLength%20entity%2Dheader,the%20request%20been%20a%20GET.) puedes revisar eso también

Comment: Gracias por toda tu ayuda, ya lo solucioné, el problema radicaba en una validación en el controlador donde if($request->hasFile('arrayFiles')){ ... } , y la data se enviaba en archivos individuales (arrayFiles0, arrayFiles1).

Comment: Perfecto, entonces si residía en el controlador; que gusto, suerte!!